# Embedded tomcat ClassDefNotFound exception sometimes?

Tags: java, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have 2 maven projects A and B. Project A is a dependency of project b.
I can access everything in project A while compiling. When I tomcat:run my project b through maven tomcat plugin i get classdefnotfoundexception but once a day after clean-installing projects many times it works until i make a tiny change in project a then it starts giving me the exceptions for hours.

What is the reason of this and why does it work sometimes?

**EDIT** Here's what i get in spring 2, if i use spring 4 its the same error but instead it says ClassDefNotFoundException.

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring-ws
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import com.test.projecta.ClassOne cannot be 
resolved
The import com.test.projecta.ClassTwo cannot be 
resolved
...
```

Adding projecta in 
pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>prx</groupId>
        <artifactId>projecta</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.11-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

I can access the imports when writing the code and like I said the project works sometimes after clean-installing many times. Could it be a classloader issue?

**EDIT 2**
I still get the same error but now only the JAXB class imports are giving me the error. Project A is using maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate classes from xsd. and target/generated-sources/xjc folder is in the build path.

Comment: Posting some code would surely help. How about for example the class that is not being found? And the relevant parts of the stacktrace maybe?

Comment: Posted the stacktrace. the package/class names I dont have permission to share but you probably get the idea

Comment: I get the idea but the code of the class would be really useful. If nothing else, at least the static variables in it. That can cause the type of intermittent issues you described. And for the "Could it be a classloader issue?". You have an issue with classloading, but this will not be a bug in the classloader. I am willing to bet a beer on it.

Comment: After another clean-install the error message has changed. Now only JAXB classes that are generated with maven-jaxb2-plugin are giving the import error. i dont know if this changes anything

Comment: The global problem is that you think that A is a dependency of B, and it's true, but one way or another, here, you have also B that is a dependency of A. a third module should appear.